# Android kitkat webview css positioning

Tags: android, html, css, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an android app which uses webview. I have 3 elements in my app and I use css to position them on top of the screen. I use percentages for their width,height and positions. the html file works perfectly fine in desktop and mobile chrome browser. But when I try it in webview the positions are not correct and seems the css has something wrong. this problem doesn't occur when I tried the app on android 4.2 but happens on android 4.4.
I know there are some changes in Webview of android 4.4 but migration document didn't help. 
Here's a link of cssdesk that shows my html and css : 
http://www.cssdesk.com/Z98q3
 I'll appreciate if you can help me with this.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've already tried this, but try putting this in your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=no; initial-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; target-densityDpi=device-dpi;">
```

You might have to restyle your buttons a bit, because this breaks android's rendering of buttons sometimes, but just setting a background colour should fix that.